# Login Android Java

Tags: java, android, login

Hola amigos buenas noches, espero se encuentren super con sus familia, les quería hacer una consulta estoy implementando un login en mi proyecto y me aparece error me podrían ayudar con el código por favor, aquí les dejo el código java y es en esta parte que se me pone en rojo como corrigiendo:

`btnLogin.setOnClickListener(setContentView(R.layout.activity_main));`

Este es mi código:

```
package com.example.jonnathanarzolafinal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import static android.app.ProgressDialog.show;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtEmail;

private EditText txtPass;

private Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtPass = findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

//en esta linea de abajo me aparece con rojo por debajo
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(setContentView(R.layout.activity_main));
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override


        public void onClick(View v) {


            String username = txtEmail.getText().toString();


            String password = txtPass.getText().toString();


            // Inicio de sesión exitoso
            if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin123"))

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inicio de sesión exitoso", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                // Credenciales inválidas
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Credenciales inválidas", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }
       };
   }
}
```

se los agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

básicamente tu error es que estas llamando mal al evento del botón, debería ser algo así:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    //aquí tu código
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta linea es incorrecta, en donde debes definir un listener estas definiendo llamar setContentView() para cargar un layout, no tiene sentido.

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(setContentView(R.layout.activity_main));
```

realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
package com.example.jonnathanarzolafinal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import static android.app.ProgressDialog.show;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtEmail;

private EditText txtPass;

private Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtPass = findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    //* Corrección...
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = txtPass.getText().toString();

                // Inicio de sesión exitoso
                if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin123"))

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inicio de sesión exitoso",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    // Credenciales inválidas
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Credenciales inválidas",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

También puedes usar Lambda:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtEmail;

private EditText txtPass;

private Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtPass = findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

     //* Corrección...
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String username =  "txtEmail.getText().toString()";
            String password = "txtPass.getText().toString()";

            // Inicio de sesión exitoso
            if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin123"))

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inicio de sesión exitoso",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                // Credenciales inválidas
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Credenciales inválidas",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
   }
}
```